# R: harder pivot_longer arguments

Tags: r, pivot, tidyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe with these names:

```
df <- tribble( ~ state, ~ county, ~ kfr_asian_pooled_p25, ~ kfr_asian_pooled_p75, 
               ~ kfr_black_pooled_p25, ~ kfr_black_pooled_p75, 
               ~ kfr_pooled_pooled_p25, ~ kfr_pooled_pooled_p75, ~ kfr_white_pooled_p25, 
               ~ kfr_white_pooled_p75, ~ kids_count, ~ kfr_asian_pooled_p25_se, 
               ~ kfr_asian_pooled_p75_se, ~ kfr_black_pooled_p25_se, 
               ~ kfr_black_pooled_p75_se, ~ kfr_white_pooled_p25_se, 
               ~ kfr_white_pooled_p75_se,
               1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17)
```

Of course the dataset is giant, but what I want to achieve is to pivot longer using its maximum potential. I mean grabbing several variables at the same time and pivot them and their names.

```
df <- tribble(~ state, ~ county, ~ kids_count,   ~ race, ~ percentile,   ~ se, ~ value,
                     1,       2,            3,  "asian",        "p25",   TRUE,   value,
                     2,       3,            4,  "black",        "p25",   TRUE,   value,
                     3,       4,            5,  "white",        "p25",   TRUE,   value,
                     1,       2,            3,  "asian",        "p75",   TRUE,   value,
                     2,       3,            4,  "black",        "p75",   TRUE,   value,
                     3,       4,            5,  "white",        "p75",   TRUE,   value,
                     1,       2,            3,  "asian",        "p25",  FALSE,   value,
                     2,       3,            4,  "black",        "p25",  FALSE,   value,
                     3,       4,            5,  "white",        "p25",  FALSE,   value,
                     1,       2,            3,  "asian",        "p75",  FALSE,   value,
                     2,       3,            4,  "black",        "p75",  FALSE,   value,
                     3,       4,            5,  "white",        "p75",  FALSE,   value)
```

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: `kids_count` is constant over state and county, right?; also, in your example output, it appears as though you have se T/F backwards, but I might be not understanding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to `pivot_longer` just the percentile columns and then split the names to create separate columns if I'm understanding correctly. The `tidyselect` functions such as `matches` are very useful for selecting similarly named columns. I’ve also used `str_split` from the `stringr` package to help create the new character columns. You could always reorganize the columns with `select` or `relocate` if the order is important to you.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
```

```r
df_long <-
  df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = matches("[p25]|[p75]"), names_to = "percentile") %>%
  mutate(se = grepl("se", percentile),
         race = stringr::str_split(percentile, "_", simplify = TRUE)[,2],
         percentile = stringr::str_split(percentile, "_", simplify = TRUE)[,4])

df_long
#> # A tibble: 14 x 7
#>    state county kids_count percentile value se    race  
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <lgl> <chr> 
#>  1     1      2         11 p25            3 FALSE asian 
#>  2     1      2         11 p75            4 FALSE asian 
#>  3     1      2         11 p25            5 FALSE black 
#>  4     1      2         11 p75            6 FALSE black 
#>  5     1      2         11 p25            7 FALSE pooled
#>  6     1      2         11 p75            8 FALSE pooled
#>  7     1      2         11 p25            9 FALSE white 
#>  8     1      2         11 p75           10 FALSE white 
#>  9     1      2         11 p25           12 TRUE  asian 
#> 10     1      2         11 p75           13 TRUE  asian 
#> 11     1      2         11 p25           14 TRUE  black 
#> 12     1      2         11 p75           15 TRUE  black 
#> 13     1      2         11 p25           16 TRUE  white 
#> 14     1      2         11 p75           17 TRUE  white
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I opted for this solution only adding:
%>% 
  filter(percentile != "n") %>% 
  mutate(percentile = if_else(percentile == "p25", "25th percentile", "75th percentile"))

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this, if I understand what you want

(First, a quick explanation of the `pivot_longer()` options that I use)

- `cols` selects the columns you want to pivot
- `names_to` with multiple elements allows us to pivot into multiple columns
- `names_prefix` allows us to remove a common prefix across the columns that we want to pivot
- `name_sep` allows us to indicate how the multiple names in `names_to` are broken up in the original columns

```
pivot_longer(
  df,
  cols = starts_with("kfr"),
  names_to=c("race", "pooled", "percentile", "se"), 
  names_prefix="kfr_", 
  names_sep="_"
) %>% 
  select(!pooled) %>% 
  mutate(se=!is.na(se))


# A tibble: 14 x 7
   state county kids_count race   percentile se    value
   <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>  <chr>      <lgl> <dbl>
 1     1      2         11 asian  p25        FALSE     3
 2     1      2         11 asian  p75        FALSE     4
 3     1      2         11 black  p25        FALSE     5
 4     1      2         11 black  p75        FALSE     6
 5     1      2         11 pooled p25        FALSE     7
 6     1      2         11 pooled p75        FALSE     8
 7     1      2         11 white  p25        FALSE     9
 8     1      2         11 white  p75        FALSE    10
 9     1      2         11 asian  p25        TRUE     12
10     1      2         11 asian  p75        TRUE     13
11     1      2         11 black  p25        TRUE     14
12     1      2         11 black  p75        TRUE     15
13     1      2         11 white  p25        TRUE     16
14     1      2         11 white  p75        TRUE     17
```

Comment: Not clear to me why you’re selecting out `kids_count`?

Comment: @zephryl, thanks was related to my initial question to the OP, but I should not have it there.. adjusted. Thanks again

Comment: @TrainingPizza - of course! very helpful! - I've added your suggestion to use `mutate(se=!is.na(se))`

Comment: Hit delete on my comment, but again a nice solution and explanation

Answer (score 1):

An option using `separate()`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c('state', 'county', 'kids_count')) %>%
  separate(name, into = c(NA, 'race', NA, 'percentile', 'se'), sep = '_') %>%
  mutate(se = !is.na(se))

# # A tibble: 14 x 7
#   state county kids_count race   percentile se    value
#    <dbl>  <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>  <chr>      <lgl> <dbl>
#  1     1      2         11 asian  p25        FALSE     3
#  2     1      2         11 asian  p75        FALSE     4
#  3     1      2         11 black  p25        FALSE     5
#  4     1      2         11 black  p75        FALSE     6
#  5     1      2         11 pooled p25        FALSE     7
#  6     1      2         11 pooled p75        FALSE     8
#  7     1      2         11 white  p25        FALSE     9
#  8     1      2         11 white  p75        FALSE    10
#  9     1      2         11 asian  p25        TRUE     12
# 10     1      2         11 asian  p75        TRUE     13
# 11     1      2         11 black  p25        TRUE     14
# 12     1      2         11 black  p75        TRUE     15
# 13     1      2         11 white  p25        TRUE     16
# 14     1      2         11 white  p75        TRUE     17
```

Comment: I like the illustration of the use of `separate` here!  Not sure if you've handled the kids_count correctly - I wasn't sure how the OP wanted it either?

Comment: @langtang: I'll gladly complete the consensus around the interpretation of the question as not involving a pivot of ```kids_count```. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We could combine `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` and `cSplit` from `süöotstaclshape`

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -c(state, county, kids_count)
    ) %>%  
  cSplit("name", "_") %>% 
  select(state, county, kids_count, race=name_2, percentile=name_4, se=name_5, value)
```

```
    state county kids_count   race percentile   se value
 1:     1      2         11  asian        p25 <NA>     3
 2:     1      2         11  asian        p75 <NA>     4
 3:     1      2         11  black        p25 <NA>     5
 4:     1      2         11  black        p75 <NA>     6
 5:     1      2         11 pooled        p25 <NA>     7
 6:     1      2         11 pooled        p75 <NA>     8
 7:     1      2         11  white        p25 <NA>     9
 8:     1      2         11  white        p75 <NA>    10
 9:     1      2         11  asian        p25   se    12
10:     1      2         11  asian        p75   se    13
11:     1      2         11  black        p25   se    14
12:     1      2         11  black        p75   se    15
13:     1      2         11  white        p25   se    16
14:     1      2         11  white        p75   se    17
```